# Send custom email for cash on delivery orders

Tags: email, custom, payment-methods

I want to send a custom email for each order that is selected cash on delivery payment method. I want to send the same email just with an additional text which is static custom text. Any help for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an observer to listen for the `sales_order_place_after` event and put your logic in the observer function:

**1) Create a module or update your config.xml**

Put your observer in the `<events>` section like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            ...
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_place_after_cod_mail>
                        <class>your_module/observer</class>
                        <method>sendCodMail</method>
                    </sales_order_place_after_cod_mail>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**2) Create your Observer**

in app/etc/CODEPOOL/YOURNAMESPACE/YOURMODULE/Model/Observer.php

```
class Yournamespace_Yourmodule {
    public function sendCodMail(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        //check if order has cash on delivery payment method
        //send e-mail
    }
}
```